# se puede crear métodos no abstractos en una clase abstracta en java?

Tags: java, java-8, método, clase-abstracta

hola verán llevo aprendiendo un poco de java desde cero hasta el momento entendí que cuando creamos una clase abstracta en Java sus métodos deben ser abstractos y estos se sobrescriben si heredamos de esta clase entonces no se si me estoy confundiendo por que revisaba la API , específicamente en la Clase JComponent según la descripción es abstracta `public abstract class JComponent` pero en sus metodos por ejemplo `paintComponent(Graphics g)` esta declarado como    `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` y bien esa es mi duda ¿ no debería ser abstracto los método si la clase JComponent es abstracta?.

Comment: Dentro de una clase abstracta puede haber métodos abstractos (obligamos a implementarlos al heredar de ella)  y también puede haber métodos no abstractos. Aquí tienes una explicación buena: https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=668:clases-y-metodos-abstractos-en-java-abstract-class-clases-del-api-ejemplos-codigo-y-ejercicios-cu00695b&catid=68&Itemid=188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La especificación no obliga a que una clase abstracta tenga métodos abstractos. Es decir, podrías tener una clase abstracta con todos los métodos ya implementados, aunque no podrías instanciarla directamente, sino que deberías crear una clase que extendiera de esta, no abstracta, e instanciarla.

Resumiendo:

- Una clase abstracta puede tener, o no, métodos abstractos.
- Una clase con uno o más métodos abstractos debe ser declarada abstracta.
- Una clase abstracta puede combinar métodos abstractos con métodos ya implementados.
- Una clase abstracta no puede ser instanciada directamente.
- Una clase abstracta debe ser extendida para instanciarse, implementando sus métodos abstractos, de haberlos.

[Referencia](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Comment: gracias pablo ya puedo tener un visión diferente sobre este tema

Answer (score 1):

Más bien lo que piensas de una Clase abstracta, se refiere más a un interface, donde sus métodos eran abstractos. Y digo eran, porque desde Java 8, ya se pueden implementar métodos por defecto con su implementación ya incluida.